# iOS designer not rendering storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, storyboard

In the Xamarin.IOS editor I get this error:

"There was a problem parsing the XML in this document"

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at MonoTouch.Design.ProxiedView.set_UseSafeArea (System.Boolean value) [0x00001] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.154.3/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/ProxiedView.cs:944
at MonoTouch.Design.ProxiedViewController.UpdateLayoutGuides (MonoTouch.Design.Catalog utilityCatalog, MonoTouch.Design.IosDocument rootModel) [0x002ac] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.154.3/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/ProxiedViewController.cs:238
at MonoTouch.Design.Storyboard.UpdateLayoutGuides (MonoTouch.Design.Catalog utilityCatalog) [0x00017] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.154.3/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Storyboard.cs:132
at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.LoadXml (System.Func`1[TResult] getDoc, System.Boolean shouldTryUpgrade, System.String fileName) [0x00310] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.154.3/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:466
```

I tried disabling things and retracing every step I made doing the storyboard, the only thing that half worked was disabling autolayout, but it destroyed my layout.
The thing is that it works perfect in the app and xcode but in the VS iOS designer it doesn't work, and I need it to add the ids of the components to use them my ViewController, in my project it's the only way to add ids.

I´m lost, if you need any extra info ask me, I pasted the important (or so I think) part of the logs, they were too long.

This is the iPad version of a storyboard that works perfectly, it was based of that storyboard (copied and pasted then edited to fit with iPad)

This is the storyboard: https://pastebin.com/QAHEBne0

Comment: you can add your storyboard file, my understanding is that your storyboard file is broken, maybe from a merge or something like this.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/QAHEBne0

Comment: can you try to replace your with this https://pastebin.com/Zace8i16 I think it should be fine

Comment: Will do on Monday when I get back to work, thanks!

Comment: Hi, I was going to try it today but the pastebin has been removed, can you post it again? Thank you.

Comment: okay, it should be this one https://pastebin.com/W9D606up

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you! If you don't mind, post an answer explaining what was wrong and I will gladly upvote it and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your file was that somehow you have constraints related with the safeArea but it was not turn on in the file.

I fix it when I open the file in my Xcode and just turn in on(check the image)
[image]

the result is `useSafeAreas="YES"` added to document tag on the second row in your xml

Please, check your constraints carefully it is possible some of them to be broken or deleted.